# How to get currency and language data from rest countries api v3.1

Tags: reactjs

I am working in a react practice project . I am trying to make an application where someone can find data about any countries.I am working with rest countries api v3.1 . Everything was going well untill i reached here . I am trying to show currency and language depanding on each countries.But the problem is that language and currency data are stored in an object where every obj has seperate name. Suppose if i go to iceland and try to access language i have to write data.languages.isl and if i go to spain and try to access language i have to write data.languages.spa.I am also facing the same problem with currency data. can anyone tell me how can i access these data.

This is how the data look like = [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgngx.png)

Comment: Are you just looking for [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I use the `Object.Values()` method. It returns an array of the values without the keys. You can check [MDN docs for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) about that. Here's a snippet of my code. This should work. By the way, I'm using JSX.

```
import {
  useRouter
} from 'next/router';
import {
  useState
} from 'react';

const fetchData = async(url) => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const jsonData = await res.json();
  return jsonData;
};

const country = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const router = useRouter();
  const {
    id
  } = router.query;
  fetchData(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${id}`).then((data) =>
    setData(data)
  );

  //here's the important part
  {
    data &&
      data.map(
        ({

            languages,
          },
          i
        ) => {
          const lang = Object.values(languages);
          return ( <
              p >
              <
              span className = "font-semibold" >
              Languages: {
                ' '
              } <
              /span> {
              lang.map((el, i) => ( <
                span key = {i}> {
                  ` ${el},`
                } < /span>
              ))
            } </p>
        )
      })
}
```